# Wrong "if" condition output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Would like some help !

[The task I recieved :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqhqh.png)

the code I wrote :

```
guessed_letter = input('Guess a letter: ')
if len(guessed_letter) == 1 and guessed_letter in string.ascii_lowercase[:26]:
    print(guessed_letter.lower())
elif len(guessed_letter) > 1 and guessed_letter in string.ascii_lowercase[:26]:
    print("Error 1")
elif guessed_letter == 1 and guessed_letter != string.ascii_lowercase[:26]:
    print("Error 2")
elif len(guessed_letter) != 1 and guessed_letter not in string.ascii_lowercase[:26]:
    print("Error 3")
```

My problem is when I try and give an input of "aa" the output comes out Error 3 and not Error 1 .

How can I proceed ?

Comment: Because "guessed letter" (a misnomer) is actually a string of two characters, and `string.ascii_lowercase[:26]` only lists one of each character. So, the length of the input is not equal to one, and `"aa"` does not appear in your string check. It gives exactly the expected output.

Comment: how can i fix it then ? 
would love some help since i'm new to python and programming.

Comment: From my side, I think I've given you enough to try think about the problem slightly differently, because it looks like an assignment. Perhaps you could call `list()` on the input to split the string and deal with each individual character?

Comment: I see. 
Thanks for the help !  Much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any chance for some more help ? Still can't solve the problem .
Need to solve it without loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
guessed_letter = input('Guess a letter: ')
if len(guessed_letter) == 1 and guessed_letter in string.ascii_lowercase[:26]:
    print(guessed_letter.lower())
elif len(guessed_letter) > 1:
    for letter in guessed_letter:
        if letter not in string.ascii_lowercase[:26]:
            print('Error 3')
        else:
            print('Error 1')
elif guessed_letter == 1 and guessed_letter not in string.ascii_lowercase[:26]:
    print('Error 2')
```

Another solution without loops:

```
guessed_letter = input('Guess a letter: ')
if len(guessed_letter) == 1 and guessed_letter in string.ascii_lowercase[:26]:
    print(guessed_letter.lower())
elif len(guessed_letter) > 1:
    new_strings = list(string.ascii_lowercase[:26])
    new_strings.extend(list(set(list(guessed_letter))))
    new_strings = list(set(new_strings))
    if len(list(string.ascii_lowercase[:26])) < len(new_strings):
        print('Error 3')
    else:
        print('Error 1')
elif guessed_letter == 1 and guessed_letter not in string.ascii_lowercase[:26]:
    print('Error 2')
```

Comment: Is there another way to do it without loops ? since i haven't learned it yet.

Comment: @LiranSarel added a solution that does not use loops.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! 
I don't think i would've ever come up with that solution . Understood it all . 
Is there any way i can contact you for further help with some things ? @OzgurBagci